# Mediawiki: Special:ConfirmEmail denied access

Tags: mediawiki

When, after creating a new account via sysop, the user gets an email:
"Someone, probably you,..... " followed (eventually) by:
 "..?title=Special:ConfirmEmail/jfdwotv(CODE)dofijnv"

When this is clicked through, I get access denied (after logging in as that user).
Tried adding "Special:ConfirmEmail" to the $wgWhitelistRead - doesn't work - I suspect that the code after "Special:ConfirmEmail/... is not matching the whitelist entry.

Any suggestions?
regards,
Duncan

Answer (score 1):

After testing your scenario, no problem for me with MediaWiki 1.25 (current dev version). I suggest you to update your MediaWiki installation. If you need more help, please include the MediaWiki version you are using, and relevant configuration parameters (wgWhitelistRead, wgGroupPermissions, wgLanguageCode) in your LocalSettings.php.

If you suspect a bug, please open a report on https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org. See also: https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=confirmemail

The exact scenario I tested:

- Create a fresh MediaWiki installation as a private wiki (wgGroupPermissions['*']: ['createaccount']=false, ['edit']=false, ['read']=false; no wgWhitelistRead)
- As sysop, create an account by sending the password by mail to the user, logout as sysop
- As the user, click on the Special:EmailConfirm link, log in with the sent password, then MediaWiki redirects to Special:EmailConfirm and validate the account, logout as user
- As sysop, create an other account by writing the password of the user, logout as sysop
- As the user, click on the Special:EmailConfirm link, log in with the specified password, then MediaWiki redirects to Special:EmailConfirm and validate the account, logout as user